厳密性 why here is used like an adjective despite the を
日向さんってそんなにすごい人なんですか？
(凄い、の定義を聞こうとして、やめた。こういう厳密性を問う話し方は井江には似合わないと思ったからだった.)
For what I understand the character is wondering about the other definition of すごい。Then he stops asking because he think that type of strict question doesn't fit the other person.
"厳密性を" seems to be used like an adjective to me? Why is the を here?

If you consider 厳密性 as a noun, hence allowing for を, you would convey the same meaning:
. .....a way of speaking, calling into question/deploying (問う)a strictness (厳密性) like this (こういう).
